# Using JavaScript create a SharePoint view of all checked out files

Tags: javascript

I am just learning SharePoint on 2013.  I need to create a view using JavaScript to list all checked out files throughout a site.  I need to be sure to look through all libraries.  Can anyone assist or point me where to look?

Comment: Hi, do you require all checkout file by a logged in user or all checkout file

Answer (score 1):

Use content Search Webpart to query the document content type and find out the files in check-out state intead of using javascript to query all sources.

Answer (score 0):

if you require to show only document that are checkout by current user you can the OOB web part "Relevant Document".
For reference [link](http://www.documentmanagementworkflowinfo.com/sharepoint-2013/sharepoint-2013-relevant-documents-web-part.htm)